# Azure iOS Build gets stuck at Generating '<AppName>.app.dSYM' step

Tags: ios, azure, azure-devops, pipeline, fastlane

I am trying to set up a pipeline for an iOS application using Fastlane and Match and I have followed the following guide.

[Azure iOS Pipeline Guide](https://help.testapp.io/azure-pipeline/)

Is there anything that I am missing?
I have checked the certificates and the provisioning profile and everything is fine. It also runs locally, but fails only in the pipeline. Any help to point me in the right direction would be really helpful.

Thanks.

I have tried running it locally and it works. From the Pipeline I have tried skip the Generating of app.dSYM step but that did not help either.

Comment: Can you share more details about the issue, such as the pipeline definition and debug logs? To see more logs, you can enable the variable “system.debug”(set the value to “true”) in your pipeline.

Comment: The keychain was the problem here, I have created a new keychain with a password in FastFile and it worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by creating a new keychain in my Fastfile and using the keychain name and password in the  match action.